# Collecting user information(email, ip address, etc) from string column of databricks table

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a string column in databricks table that containing text data. I want to extract user information from this column like email, IP address and social security number.

I am currently applying regex on column to get these values like:

```
%sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE  col like '%_@__%.__%';
```

same for extracting other information using other regex on same column.
Is there any generic query that can be used to find these user information from column?  And do we have any method other than using regex?

Example column values:

- abc@gmail.com
- test@gmail.com
- testing
- testing
- 123456
- 11.0.6.13
- 22.44.66.7
- testing
- 49.37.4.136
- 103.136.64.304

Comment: 1. Do you can show example value with your column? 2. split(...)

Comment: Edited my question with examples

Comment: I think like, regex

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using regexp_extract, eg

```
%sql
SELECT *,
  regexp_extract( yourColumn, '(.*@.*)', 1 ) AS email,
  regexp_extract( yourColumn, '([a-z]+)', 1 ) AS someText,
  regexp_extract( yourColumn, '(\\d+)', 1 ) AS someDigits,
  regexp_extract( yourColumn, '([0-9]{6})', 1 ) AS sixDigits,
  regexp_extract( yourColumn, '(\\d+\.\\d+\.\\d+\.\\d+)', 1 ) AS ipAddress
FROM tmp
```

My results with your sample data:

[image: My results]

Your approach will have to be more sophisticated, the regex for email is wrong for example.